# View Layer insertSublayer is not updating the layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, colors, calayer

I am trying to add a gradient layer to my view, first time when I run the code it inserts the layer perfectly but every 10 sec I run the same function again to change the layer but it doesn't update the layer.

```
if ([[self.view.layer sublayers] count]>1) {
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer=[ColorUtilities randomGradient];
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    //[self.view.layer replaceSublayer:[[self.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] with:gradientLayer];
}
```

here `[ColorUtilities randomGradient]` gives me a random layer every time.

why layer `atindex:0` is not updated?

Comment: Which thread is the code called on? If it isn't the main thread you would expect no updates to the view.

Comment: I didn't copy-pasted whole code but it is called inside of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dominikweifieg comment is somewhat valid.  Just keep a flag that if you added the layer first time then replace the sublayer after that

something like this should work

```
-(void)updateGradientLayer
{
//isFirstTimeInserting is a global BOOL
    if (isFirstTimeInserting==YES) {
        CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer=[ColorUtilities randomGradient];
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
        isFirstTimeInserting=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[self.view.layer sublayers] count]>=1) {
        CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer=[ColorUtilities randomGradient];
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer above:[[self.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the new gradient layer at index 0 places it below the gradient layer you inserted the first time, so it can't be visible. Try to insert it above the last gradient layer using insertLayer:above:

Comment: this doesn't make sense to me, I am using gradient layer as background so insertingLayer:above: messes my UI, because there are other views on the UI, plus why would `replaceSublayer` not work?

Comment: Well, one thing is sure, if you insert at index 0 the layer will never be visible, because it is hidden behind your first gradient layer. ReplaceSublayer should normally work, just not the first time around since you can't call it with nil as first argument. So, try to use insertsublayer on the first call and replacesublayer on subsequent calls.